# html, css, jquery based drag & drop, resize, rotate app: export final image to jpg via php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, gd

I am trying to build a web app with html, css and jquery which lets users add multiple images on a div. Then you can drag and drop them anywhere within the div, even resize & rotate the images.

Example here: http://h1s.sg/projects/ddbp/demo/

What I need to do is, generate a final jpg on click of a button with the background image of the parent div + all resized & rotated images on it with exact position, sizes and rotation.

I know this can be done by adding each image as a layer to the background image, we can pass a JS array with position, rotation degree etc to the php script. Where I am clueless is how to convert the position, size and rotation degrees to php values and apply them.

Answer (score 1):

This library solved my problem:

https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this project: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will check this out. So the example script says I can pass any element to it. If I pass the Id of the parent Div, will it work?

Comment: This solved my problem: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image Thanks for your kind help and pointing me to the right direction.